# How to use Jstree library with meteor

Tags: meteor, jstree

I'm trying to use the Jstree jquery plugin with meteor, tried both adding the package and the the library on the compatibilty folder inside Client.
I still get undefined is not function when instantiating `$("#id").tree()`.

I can't seem to find what's wrong , even the package don't work .

Comment: We can't find what's wrong cause we have no idea what your code looks like. Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try this:

`$("#id").jstree()`